# How to export fullcalender data into iCal format?

Tags: javascript, php, ios, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar js for my event dispay and I want to export all data into iCal format.

Answer (score 5):

```
[BEGIN] => VEVENT
    [CREATED] => 20121030T105658Z
    [LAST-MODIFIED] => 20121030T105658Z
    [DTSTAMP] => 20121030T105658Z
    [SUMMARY] => Winterferien Bayern
    [DTSTART;VALUE=DATE] => 20120220
    [DTEND;VALUE=DATE] => 20120225
    [URL] => http://www.schulferien.org
    [DESCRIPTION] => Alle Termine auf www.schulferien.org
    [TRANSP] => TRANSPARENT
    [UID] => Winterferien-Bayern-201202251205422257@schulferien.org
    [END] => VEVENT
```

PRODID
The PRODID are your app / company details in the format Business

BEGIN:VEVENT
The start tag for an event. You can have as many vevents as you require.

SUMMARY
This is the event title.

UID
A unique ID for the event. This is important and required, and allows you to push changes to event details after they have been created. If you are retrieving database rows, the primary key is an ideal candidate for the UID value.

STATUS (optional. default value is CONFIRMED)
The event status is optional and can be one of CONFIRMED, TENTATIVE, CANCELLED. A cancelled event shows with a line through text decoration on iOS.

DTSTART, DTEND
The event start and end timestamp. This should be formatted as demonstrated using the defined iCal format.If your dates are not already in the UTC timezone, you should convert them to UTC before outputting as this is the expected timezone when the timestamp ends with “Z”. There are options to specify a timezone which are beyond the scope of this tutorial.

It is worth noting that if you enter an address or phone number into the DESCRIPTION field (which I haven’t documented) in plain text, iOS will auto-link the text and will jump to the Maps app or Phone app with the details pre-filled.

END:VEVENT
The close tag for an event. Remember, you can have as many vevents as you require.